# Rgd 2 Hard Disk on 1 server but only 1 is the web server on linking

Tags: apache, centos

Rgd 2 Hard Disk on 1 server but only 1 is the web server

This is my hard disk structure

```
/dev/sda3             909G  798G   65G  93% /
/dev/sdb1             1.8T  196M  1.7T   1% /extraspace

The /extraspace is recently setup with 2tb space
```

I got a webroot setup with cpanel/whm apache on this path

```
/home/user1/www
```

There is 1 folder call /assets which contains all my media, pictures etc.

How do I like push the files to /extraspace from /assets and still retain /assets link, so when user enter /assets, its actually entering /extraspace

such as

```
http://mydomain.com/assets actually opening files locate on /extraspace
```

**Thanks for helping !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is such a common case that Apache has a very common directive called `Alias` for this.

What you want is

```
Alias /assets /extraspace/assets
```

and then move all of your media files from your old assets directory to the new one under `extraspace`.

Documentation is [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html#outside) for Apache 2.2, and [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#outside) for Apache 2.4 .